# ポリシーの翻訳：Inauthentic usage policy

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

この投稿は [Inauthentic usage policy](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) の翻訳案です。

---

Title: 不正使用ポリシー

ユーザーのたゆまぬ努力と貢献のおかげで繁栄するコミュニティの成功が実現します。ネットワークの正常な通常作業を妨げる悪意のある行為や不正行為は許可されません。

プラットフォームの信頼性を確保するため、[Stack Exchange ネットワーク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)の利用規約および[セキュリティ](https://stackexchange.com/about/security)ガイダンスに違反するシステムの使用は許可されません。また、ユーザー、コンテンツ、および/またはネットワークに不要な負荷、混乱、および/または害を直接引き起こす行為も禁止しています。

さらに、次のようなシステムの不正使用は許可されません：

- コンテンツやユーザーの人気やスコアを人為的に高めること。
- 意図的な投票を通じてを人為的に信用度を高めること。
- 特定のユーザーに報酬や罰を与えるかのように見える投票パターン、またはコンテンツへの投票を無視して行われているかのような投票パターン。
- システムやモデレーターを回避しようと複数のアカウントやプロフィールを使用すると、制限が課せられます。システム、モデレーター、そして課された制限を回避するために使用しない、或いは複数のアカウントを使用するためのルールに違反しない限り、1 人の個人が複数のアカウントやプロフィールを使用することは許可されています。
- 異なる人々の間でアカウントやプロフィールを共有する行為は、同じ企業や組織に所属している場合や代理で行動している場合でも同様、許可されません。各アカウントやプロフィールは、その持ち主の個人だけが使用することができます。Stack Exchange は、アカウント/プロフィールがこの制限の対象外であることを書面で明示的に許可する場合もあります。
- 偽のアカウントの使用を含み、これに限定しない、不正行為の調整。
- 「[他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)」に違反する形で、Web サイトや書籍、その他のオンライン/オフラインツールからコンテンツを盗用またはコピーし、適切な引用を明示しないこと。.

Answer (score 1):

翻訳の前に内容に関しての共通理解が必要なように思いました。現時点では全体として翻訳の当否が判断できません。

> - コンテンツやユーザーの人気やスコアを人為的に高めること。
> - 意図的な投票を通じてを人為的に信用度を高めること。

この2つは何が違うのでしょうか？

> 特定のユーザーに報酬や罰を与えるかのように見える投票パターン、またはコンテンツへの投票を無視して行われているかのような投票パターン。

後段が具体的に何を指してるのか想像できませんでした。

> 「他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法」に違反する形で、Web サイトや書籍、その他のオンライン/オフラインツールからコンテンツを盗用またはコピーし、適切な引用を明示しないこと。.

一般論として指摘すると、日本の著作権法とは整合しません。｢適切な出典(文脈上「適切な引用」は誤訳です)の明示」だけではなく、引用部が全体として「従」であることが求められます。

それ以前に、過去、明らかな盗用についても「有益な内容だからOK」「権利問題はコミュニティとして対処するものではない」と放置宣言がされています。よって、サイトの運用上は盗用は｢不正行為」には含まれないというのが現状です。

Comment: 2つ目は実際には「内容を無視した投票パターン」で、単なる誤訳かと思います。

Comment: 権利問題の件、少なくともコミュニティ（ユーザー）によるモデレーションと Stack Exchange 社による運営は別です。サイトの運用というと両者が含まれ、たとえば著作権であれば https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact から DMCA takedown が可能であり、不正が認められます。

Comment: 日本の著作権法と整合しないとのことですが、「引用」の部分の元の単語が attribution なので、著作権法上の引用ではないです。訳語を変えると誤解が減りそうですね。また「適切な出典がないのは駄目」と言っているのみで「適切な出典があれば OK」とまでは言っていないです。

Comment: コミュニティとして介入しないのなら「不正行為」として定義する必要はなくここに記載する必要はないということです。(利用者ではない)権利者とSE社が直接解決すべき問題なのであればどうせここに何が書いてあるかは関係ないので。

Comment: みなさま、ご投稿やコメントありがとうございました。

Comment: @suzukis 「ここに記載する必要はない」というご意見を尊重し、本投稿を削除させていただきます。このコメントが読めるように、少し間をおいてから削除いたしますね！

Comment: 《1. 「人気やスコア」と「信用度」の違い》
多くの場合これらは直接に関係しており、私も分ける必要を感じません。
しかし、例えば[懸賞](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)を通じて、信用度だけ上げる方法もありますので、彼らは分けて書いたのでしょう。

《2. 「コンテンツへの投票を無視して」の意味》
cubickさんのコメントの通り、「disregard to the content」の誤訳と思われ、修正が必須ですね。

《3. 著作権法との整合》
まず、法で定められていることが、利用規約にも書かれているはず（いるべき）、という前提で読むべきではないと思います。
ここに書かれているのは、このサイト独自の制限であり、法に従った上で、さらにこれらのルールに従って下さい、という意味でしょう。
例えば、出典への直接のリンクは、法では求められていないかも知れませんが、このサイトでは必須、という風にです。
「適切な引用」は、おっしゃる通り誤訳と思います。

Comment: @aki Suzukisさんが、「ここに記載する必要はない」と言及している「ここ」とは、不正使用ポリシーのことです。
このメタ質問のことでは有りません。
「記載する必要がない」と主張されているのは最後の項目（出典の明示を求める項）です。
（原文に関して我々の意見が通ることは無いでしょうから、私はこれに関して議論はしません）

Comment: @mjy  ご説明ありがとうございます。せっかちなもので、読み違えてしまい大変申し訳ありません！それでは今の所は投稿を削除せずにコミュニティとしての訳を反映できる方向で進めてよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: こちらはもちろん日本語版としての翻訳案ですので、日本語版に適さない文章であれば本文を削除なさるのが良いのではないかと思います。また、誤訳であると思った方が編集なさるのが良いように思います。編集合戦のようなものは好まれませんが、もし改善できる箇所があり、時間に余裕のある方がおられたら、そうなさるのがよろしいのではないかと感じています。

Answer (score 1):

Suzukisさんの投稿で出ている点を含め、修正案です。

#### 2項目

タイポ修正。

現在:

> 意図的な投票を通じてを人為的に信用度を高めること。

修正案:

> 意図的な投票を通じて信用度を人為的に高めること。

#### 3項目

「disregard to the content」で区切り、「内容を無視」と解釈。「かのように見える」はやや控え目すぎるかと思うので、「見なされる」に。

現在:

> 特定のユーザーに報酬や罰を与えるかのように見える投票パターン、またはコンテンツへの投票を無視して行われているかのような投票パターン。

修正案:

> 特定のユーザーに報酬や罰を与えることのみを目的としているか、内容を無視して行なわれている、と見なされる投票パターン。

#### 6項目

「不正行為の調整」は理解が難しいです。原文の「Coordinating inauthentic behavior」で言われているのは、Meta（Facebook）発祥の用語「Coordinated Inauthentic Behavior (CIB)」のことではないでしょうか。

「CIB」には定まった訳が無いようです。

- [「協調的違反行動」](https://note.com/ichi_twnovel/n/nc1e0c22aa003)
- [「協調的な不正行為」](https://sustainablejapan.jp/2020/05/12/facebook-cib-report/49391)
- [「組織的な本物でない行動」](https://digiday.jp/platforms/facebooks-latest-inauthentic-behavior-campaign-raises-questions-user-quality/)

などの訳例が見つかりました。上の仮定の元、修正案を出します。

現在:

> 偽のアカウントの使用を含み、これに限定しない、不正行為の調整。

修正案:

> 偽アカウントの使用などを通じた組織的な不正行為。

#### 7項目（最終項）

「attribution」を「出典」に（「帰属」も選択肢の一つです）。

現在:

> [他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)」に違反する形で、Web サイトや書籍、その他のオンライン/オフラインツールからコンテンツを盗用またはコピーし、適切な引用を明示しないこと。

修正案:

> 適切に出典を明示せず、[他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)」に違反する形で、Webサイトや書籍、その他のオンライン/オフラインツールからコンテンツを盗用またはコピーすること。